# Using Like in the query and SQL Injection implications

Tags: php

I know this question must have been asked most often.

But I just want to know if this code can protect me
from sql injection attack as **percent** is quoted in single. Am just worried in case of any possible attack

Can someone throws more light on this **LIKE QUERY**, or if there is any other better way thanks

```
$s =$_POST['data'];

include(pdo.php);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where name like :name OR country like :country limit 6');
$stmt->execute(array(
':name' => '%'.$s.'%',
':country' => '%'.$s.'%'
));

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
//
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You're using a prepared statement, that's the important bit, then the percentage characters in the values don't matter.

Comment: Thanks all. am good to go now